# IIFE example from MDN - A Reintroduction to Javascript page

Tags: javascript, dom, recursion, iife

The snippet below is from MDN - A reintroduction to Javascript, it is supposed to demonstrate IIFE.  I kinda see that it is supposed to count the characters in this text node but I am not sure about a couple things.  The first is why does the for statement have 2 arguments in the first argument section `var i=0, child`. The second is more general, how does it work with this function calling itself .. can someone explain the overall flow to me please?

```
var charsInBody = (function counter(elm) {
  if (elm.nodeType == 3) { // TEXT_NODE
    return elm.nodeValue.length;
  }
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0, child; child = elm.childNodes[i]; i++) {
    count += counter(child);
  }
  return count;
})(document.body);
```

Comment: for the second question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25052/in-plain-english-what-is-recursion

Comment: The comma delimited identifiers `i` and `child` are arguments of the `var` statement. It just declares and initializes `i` while only declaring `child`. The second part of your question is definitely a duplicate though, unfortunately, so you should do your part by searching for other IIFE and recursion questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

> The first is why does the for statement have 2 arguments in the first argument section var i=0,child ?

A for loop is just a condensed version of a while loop, that means that:

```
 for(declarations; condition; last) {
  body
 }
```

is the same as:

```
 declarations
 while(condition) {
   body
   last
 }
```

That means that in your case it is as:

```
 var i = 0, child; 
 while(child = elm.childNodes[i]) {
   count += counter(child);
   i++
 }
```

So actually `child` just defines a new variable before the loop